# Loading random image from a directory with php

Tags: php, arrays, .htaccess

I need to select a random image from a directory. I've seen a few approaches that use glob(); but I'm hoping to use the scandir(); function.

```
function random_img(){
$imageDir =  wptouch_get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/default-tiles/';
$images = scandir($imageDir);
$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];

return $randomImage;
}
```

The function above should pull an image but instead i'm getting this error:

*scandir("/myfile/directory/") failed to open dir: not implemented in "/myfile/directory/"*

Comment: `/images/default-tiles/` is really your **local** directory of images?  Usually you get an error like this if you are trying to list contents of a directory over a different fopen wrapper, such as HTTP.

Comment: I've edited my question so it includes the true dynamic path.

Comment: What is output when you `echo wptouch_get_bloginfo('template_directory')`?

Comment: beta.sr.local/wp-content/wptouch-data/themes/CMN-Touch-Base/iphone/

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, I think the path you are using is incorrect:

```
$imageDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 
            get_template_directory_uri() .
            '/images/default-tiles/';
```

Comment: That got me closer but in the end the only solution that has worked was this:  $imageDir = ABSPATH.'wp-content/wptouch-data/themes/CMN-Touch-Base/iphone/images/default-tiles/';

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the directory you are using isn't actually a directory on your local system, but is a URL.  You can't list files at a URL.  How would anything know what was supposed to be included?  There isn't some universally implemented magic, and resources over HTTP don't even have to correspond to files at all.

What you need to do is figure out where these files are on your local system, and use that path instead.